# Aggregating data from the US stock market in Tableau, using different time frames

Tags: tableau-api

I am a very basic user of tableau and I have not found an answer to my question.

I have a txt file that has historical daily data for 98% of all the stocks in the US, with their daily capitalization. Each stocks has its TICKER, Daily Market Value for every trading day of the year, and its SECTOR.

I did a simple time series that display `SUM([Mktval])` (sum of all individual market values) across all stocks, on a daily daily, and where I can see that the total value as of 2016 is about 24 Trillion USD, as in the image below.

[image]

When I change the view column from DAY to YEAR, I don't see the right values, but something a lot larger. So I realized that I need to do `SUM([Mktval])/252` to get the right value for a year (there are 252 trading days in a year).

If I change the view to MONTH, as in the chart below, the numbers are again wrong because 252 is not the right value to use in the division.

[image]

Is there any way that Tableau can adjust the values automatically to reflect the **AVG MktVal** across different time intervals?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace SUM(Mktval) on the Rows shelf with the following calculated field

```
avg({ fixed day(Date1) : sum(Mktval) })
```

That solution is all in one step. It is perhaps a bit more clear to use 2 steps. First, create a calculated field called **total_daily_market_value** defined as

```
{ fixed day(Date1) : sum(Mktval) }
```

Then make sure that calculated field is a measure. It is an LOD calculation that you can think of as a separate table with one value for each day showing the total market value for that day.

Drag that measure to a shelf, and then change the aggregation function to AVG(), MEDIAN(), MIN(), MAX() or STDEV() as desired. Tableau will aggregate the total_daily_market_value using your chosen aggregation function for whatever values of Date1 are in your view.

Comment: Thank you Alex. The formula is not correct, it returns the chart here http://imgur.com/a/Qs9lE

Comment: You left off the word day and the parenthesis around the Date1 field